# how to echo a specific value in array if key is not specified?

Tags: php, arrays

```
class database {
public function dataarray() {
$array = array('John', 'Alex', 'Smith','Doe','Mane','Rio');
   }
}
$export = new database();
echo $export->dataarray(); // ??? what echo code/ other style code, to show only name 'John' value.
```

I want to only echo "value" (John) of $array above. How can I achieve this if key is not specified? is it possible?

Comment: You need to return your data from the method. Then you can just access the index you want.

Comment: Why is this question down voted twice?

Answer (score 1):

```
class database { 
public function dataarray($index) { 
$array = array('John', 'Alex', 'Smith','Doe','Mane','Rio'); 
return $array[$index]; } 
} 
$export = new database(); 
echo $export->dataarray(0);
```

I would pass a param in the function and have it return that indexs values like so.

Answer (score 0):

```
class database {
public function dataarray() {
    $array = array('John', 'Alex', 'Smith','Doe','Mane','Rio');
    return $array;
   }
}

$export = new database();

echo $export->dataarray()[0];
```

Comment: You are welcome, but Ben Edwards' is potentially better.